# Change column seperated field into enters in same column SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, split

I am building a list of several company's with products they deliver to show on a map later on.
So every column is filled with a company in 1 column, and all of the products in another column seperated by ;

```
+-----------+--------------+
|  Company  |   Products   |
+-----------+--------------+
|     1     |  a; b; c; d  |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Expected outcome:

```
+-----------+--------------+
|  Company  |   Products   |
+-----------+--------------+
|     1     |  a           |
|           |  b           |
|           |  c           |
|           |  d           |
+-----------+--------------+
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: Would you like to change the current ; for \n? 
Seems like all products still in the same cell in the present expected outcome, please change it if not.
Specify which dbms you are using

Comment: The expected outcome is indeed still in the same cell.

Comment: I'm working on SQL

Comment: "SQL" is a query language, not a database product. Every relational database is a "SQL database". So please let us know which DBMS product you are using. Postgres? Oracle? Firebird? DB2? SQL Server?

Comment: SQL server working on

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server (at least the more recent versions), you can use `string_split()`:

```
select t.*, ltrim(s.value) as product
from t cross apply
     string_split(t.products, ';') s
```